# Too few arguments to function Google\Client::authenticate(), 0 passed in google.php on line 41 and exactly 1 expected

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

Hello I am trying to get access token using Google api client PHP in CodeIgniter

when I load this localhost:8080/google/callback i am getting following error

```
Too few arguments to function Google\Client::authenticate(), 0 passed in E:\wamp\www\myproject\app\Controllers\Google.php on line 41 and exactly 1 expected
```

here is code

```
public function callback(){
define('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID', 'XXXX']);
define('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET', 'XXXX');


// Create Client Request to access Google API
$client = new Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Mysite.dom.ain');
$client->setClientId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost:8080/google/callback');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload');
$client->setAccessType('offline');        // offline access
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
$client->setHttpClient(new GC(['verify' => false]));

        $client->authenticate();
        
    return $client->getAccessToken();
}
```

it will be  a great if anybody can help me sorting this.

Comment: The [authenticate](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Client.php#L224) function requires a `$code` to be passed in.

Comment: @PtrTon what should I assign in $code..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redirect user to `createAuthUrl()` to get `$_GET['code']`

You can simply do it by following way

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    return $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
$redirect = $client->createAuthUrl();
header('Location: ' . $redirect);
        exit();
}
```

where you can initially check `$_GET['code']` is exist if not request for it.

Hope this might help you.